# MYSQL query to match multiple values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble fixing a MYSQL query that will find "matches" between 2 relational tables. For example, if the TABLEA ID being passed in was 2, then I want to return all IDs from TABLEB where both TABLEA VALUES (b and c) exist for a single TABLEB ID. Hope that made sense! In this instance it wouldn't return anything. However, when passing in ID 3 it would return 13 as d and e exist within ID 13 rows in TABLEB. Any help massively appreciated!

```
TABLEA

ID | VALUE
1  | a
2  | b
2  | c
3  | d
3  | e


TABLEB

ID | VALUE
10  | a
12  | b
12  | z
13  | d
13  | e
13  | f
```

Comment: You have multiple rows with the same ID? is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query.

***UPDATE***:

**In MySQL :**

```
SELECT        tab_b.ID
FROM          TABLEB tab_b  
WHERE         tab_b.VALUE IN (SELECT      TABLEA.VALUE
                              FROM        TABLEA
                              WHERE       TABLEA.ID = 3)

GROUP BY      tab_b.ID
HAVING        COUNT(DISTINCT tab_b.VALUE) = (SELECT      COUNT(TABLEA.VALUE)
                                             FROM        TABLEA
                                             WHERE       TABLEA.ID = 3)
```

Check this Fiddle in **MySQL:** ->http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1aba/10

Fiddle in **SQL Server:** -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0d63/3

(You'll have to change the values from 2 to 3 to see the desired result)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I'd like this to be correct but I'm of the understanding that this would return 12 when I don't want it to return anything... because TABLEB ID 12 doesn't also have a value of c

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.id2
from tableA a
left join tableB b
on a.value = b.value2
where a.id = 2
and id2 is not null
```

hope this answers it for you

here is the fiddle
[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e4b1/5)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e4b1/5

Comment: This doesn't work!! Your query should result in nothing. But check your fiddle. It results in 12 being dislpayed. That's the comment the OP made on my answer. In this case, the result should be nothing. This answer therefore, is wrong

Comment: Read the question properly. If you understand it correctly, according to the given data, when you try to find the values based on the values in tableA, if the parameter is 2, then no values should be returned. If instead, 3 is provided as the parameter, then 13 should be returned.